How to merge multiple xcassets?
Our app has been using two separate xcassets catalogs for two different themes.
Recently, we noticed that these two catalogs do not have much differences, and contain unnecessary duplicated files.
We want to merge these two xcassets catalogs to get rid of the duplicated files, and keep only unique files.
How can I achieve this?
Edit: each catalog contains over 2500 files, so manual solution won't work.

Copy them to one folder?

You meant that it had the same 'content' however, different name right?

some files exist in both catalogs which cause duplication issue. for example: file1.svg exists in catalog1 and also catalog2.

I can't do manual copy as there are too much file to detect manually. over 2 thousands of files.

There is a library to check if an asset could be used from somewhere in the project. But I think this scenario is different, you need a tool to do that, maybe PhotoSwepper can help.

Asset catalogs are folders / files in your project.
Assuming you have this type of folder structure:

MyApp/

MyApp/

AppDelegate.swift
Catalog1.xcassets
Catalog2.xcassets
ViewController.swift
etc


MyApp.xcodeproj



Open Terminal and:
cd pathTo/MyApp/MyApp
mkdir CombinedAssets.xcassets
cp -Rn Catalog1.xcassets/* CombinedAssets.xcassets
cp -Rn Catalog2.xcassets/* CombinedAssets.xcassets

the -Rn means "Recursive, no-clobber"
You can now add CombinedAssets.xcassets to your project, and delete the two original catalogs.
You don't really need to create the CombinedAssets ... you could simply:
cp -Rn Catalog2.xcassets/* Catalog1.xcassets

which will "add" all files/folders from Catalog2 to Catalog1 while skipping duplicates.
It should go without saying, but: back up your files first! (just in case).
